# compactMap result is of weird type

Tags: swift

I expect `allMembers` to be of type `[Member]`. But instead its type is `[[Member]]`. Why `compactMap` does not return result of `[Member]` type?

```
class Team {
    let members = Array(repeating: Member(), count: 2)
}

class Member {
}

let teams = Array(repeating: Team(), count: 3)
let allMembers = teams.compactMap { $0.members }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need `flatMap`, not `compactMap`.

Even though previously (before Swift 4.1), `compactMap` was also called `flatMap`, it had a different implementation and function signature than the current `flatMap`, since `compactMap` can be used instead of consecutive `map` and `filter` calls to `map` each element to a new element while only keeping `non-nil` elements. On the other hand, `flatMap` flattens out nested lists while mapping elements.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap) is the still existing `flatMap` on `Sequence`, while [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907182-flatmap) is the deprecated `flatMap` on `Sequence` that was renamed to `compactMap`. As you can see, the function signature of the renamed version was

```
func flatMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Self.Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
```

, so its closure input argument returned an `Optional` value (just like `compactMap` does now), while the still existing `flatMap` has a function signature

```
func flatMap<SegmentOfResult>(_ transform: (Self.Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Element] where SegmentOfResult : Sequence
```

, which doesn't return an `Optional` in its closure.

You should use the non-deprecated `flatMap` to flatten out your nested `Array<Array<Member>>`.

```
let allMembers = teams.flatMap { $0.members }
```

Comment: `flatMap` is deprecated

Comment: flatMap is renamed as compactMap see this for e.g : https://useyourloaf.com/blog/replacing-flatmap-with-compactmap/

Comment: @YakivKovalsky no it's not. Only 1 of its 2 implementations was renamed to `compactMap`.Check my updated answer. That code in my answer was tested and is working in a playground.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some detail in @David's answer:

> Using flatMap on a sequence (like an Array) filtering anything that maps to nil is now deprecated and replaced by compactMap.

**Using flatMap on a sequence with a closure that returns an optional.**

```
Sequence.flatMap<U>(_ transform: (Element) -> U?) -> U?
```

For example:

**Rather than:**

```
let names: [String?] = ["Tom", nil, "Peter", nil, "Harry"]
let valid = names.flatMap { $0 }
```

**You have to use:**

```
let valid = names.compactMap { $0 }
// ["Tom", "Peter", "Harry"]
```

---

```
let names: [String?] = ["Tom", nil, "Peter", nil, "Harry"]
let counts = names.compactMap { $0?.count }
// [3, 5, 5]
```

> But again, Swift 4.1 does not deprecate all uses of flatMap - out of 3 cases, only one case is changing. Below two situations are as it is where you need to use flatMap:

**1) Using flatMap on a sequence with a closure that returns a sequence:**

```
Sequence.flatMap<S>(_ transform: (Element) -> S) -> [S.Element] where S : Sequence
```

Example:

```
let scores = [[5,2,7], [4,8], [9,1,3]]
let allScores = scores.flatMap { $0 }
// [5, 2, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 3]

let passMarks = scores.flatMap { $0.filter { $0 > 5} }
// [7, 8, 9]
```

**2) Using flatMap on an optional: The closure takes the non-nil value of the optional and returns an optional. If the original optional is nil then flatMap returns nil:**

```
Optional.flatMap<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) -> U?) -> U?
```

Example:

```
let input: Int? = Int("8")
let passMark: Int? = input.flatMap { $0 > 5 ? $0 : nil}
// Optional(8)
```

For more detail, please refer [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/replacing-flatmap-with-compactmap/)